# Get previous and next week days

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm able to list current week dates . But How to list previous / next week days ?

( I want to use a button to list previous and next week days. Whenever I click it will show one week before/ after )

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);     
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,  cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());        
        daydate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");       

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {   
             dates[i] = daydate.format(cal.getTime());     
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
}
```

Comment: Add or subtract 7 days from the calendar? (read the docs!)

Comment: Both, I will use prev and next button to add and subtract. But couldnt set it.

Comment: You misunderstood.  You can add or subtract 7 days, or perhaps use week of the year.  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Opps, thanks, I got it now, I will use +7 and -7 with calendar date.

Answer (score 1):

To display next week
follow below code.

```
    List next = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    start = df.format(c.getTime());
    next.add(start);
    }
   textview.setText("" + next.get(0) + "-" + next.get(6));
```

Comment: You write 2 answers to this question. one for next week and other for previous week. you can write both in ONE.

Answer (score 0):

To display previous week follow the below code:

```
    List previous = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                start = df.format(c.getTime());
                previous.add(start);
            }
            textview.setText("" + previous.get(6) + "-" + previous.get(0));
```